# JavaScript postfix a boolean / one-shot flag for throttling an event

Tags: javascript, performance, coercion

I want to use a flag once, then convert it to false no matter what, after the expression returns the truthiness:

```
var isProceding = true;
someObject.addEventListener("someEvent", doOnce); // event fires many times

function doOnce () {
    if (isProceding) {
        isProceding = false; // i want to join this line with the previous
        // do stuff
        someObject.removeEventListener("someEvent", doOnce);
    }
}
```

---

> ***from [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/coercing-booleans)***
>
> 1. `if (!isDone++) {` **343,020,200** single coercion post fix
> 2. `if (isProceding && isProceding--) {` **342,466,581 short circuit post fix**
> 3. `if (isProceding) { isProceding = false;` **338,360,292** standard
> 4. `if (0 < isProceding--) {` **278,447,221 comparison coercion post fix**
> 5. `if (isProceding --> false) {` **9,983,236 double coercion postfix**

Comment: Why do you need a flag at all, if it's just supposed to fire once, just remove the event listener ?

Comment: i dont believe removing the listener will clear the queued callstack

Comment: Ah, so you're using the variable inside the event handler to stop asynchronous code from running after the handler is removed then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a number is only falsey at 0

```
var isDone = 0;

if (!isDone++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

or

```
var isProceding = true;

if (isProceding --> false) {
    // do stuff
}
```